# Need to hide desktop application from TM's Apps tab in Windows 8.1

Tags: vb.net, windows, hide

Good evening,
I am trying to hide my visual basic program in "Applications" tab in Task Manager.

Do anybody know how can I do it?
Tried **showInTaskbar = false**, but this isn't working, still can see it.

Using Express Studio 2013 Desktop and VB project on NET. Framework 4

Comment: Try this `App.TaskVisible = False `

Comment: added it to private sub load/show, but I can still see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
Sub test()
  x.hideMyProcess
End sub
```